# python click module input for each function

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, argparse, python-click

I'm a new bee for python currently working on the Click module. So here I have a doubt to providing input for the main cli function only. But I want to provide the input for my all the function one by one. is it possible to click? Thanks for advance.

```
@click.option('--create', default='sub', help='Create')
@click.command()
def create(create):
    click.echo('create called')
    os.system('curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/create')   
@click.option('--conn', default='in', help='connect to server')
@click.command()
def conn(conn):
    click.echo('conn called')
    os.system('curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
```

and my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
     name="hello",
     version='0.1',
     py_modules=['hello'],
     install_requires=[
                    'Click',
     ],
     entry_points='''
     [console_scripts]
     hello=hello:cli
''',
)
```

My output expectation

```
$ hello --conn in
  success
  hello --create sub
  success
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want different commands based on input provided to your `hello`  cli. For that reason, Click has the useful notion of a group, a collection of commands that can be invoked.

You can reorganize your code as follows:

```py
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
def create():
    click.echo('create called')
    os.system('curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/create')

@cli.command()
def conn():
    click.echo('conn called')
    os.system('curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/')

def main():
    value = click.prompt('Select a command to run', type=click.Choice(list(cli.commands.keys()) + ['exit']))
    while value != 'exit':
        cli.commands[value]()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the calls would be:

```sh
$ hello con
$ hello create
```

It doesn't seem like you need the options, as you don't change the behaviour of each command based on the option being passed in or not. For more information, please refer to the [commands and groups Click documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/)

Comment: Yeah.. you're correct command is helpful. But my question was quote different, if I given hello conn here, my program be executed and ended right. But I need that one not be end.. it will be get ready for to get another input from user. So that input based it will call another function. I thought click.prompt will help but I don't know how to handle that. Hope you understand. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I've updated my answer with your use case. It's worth noting that's not quite the use of a command line client, but this offers a naive way of doing it.